# Компилятор выдает ошибку синтаксиса Java

Tags: java

```
class cityTour {

public cityTour() {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
}
cityTour parisTour = new cityTour();
public void ayazhanRoute(){
  System.out.println("Cобор Нотр-Дам - Площадь Отель-де-Виль - Башня Сен-Жак - Лувр - Сад Тюильри - Площадь Согласия - Елисейские поля - Площадь Трокадеро - Эйфелева башня");
}
parisTour.ayazhanRoute();
}

// класс Tourism

class Tourism {

public void averageCost(String city) {

System.out.println("Средняя стоимость однодневного тура по городу "+ city + " 300 евро");
}
}
```

Comment: а где сама ошибка с стеком трассы? Оо А вообще смотрите в `public static void main(String[] args) {
}`

Comment: Вы ему не верите? Предлагаете нам поработать компиляторами?

Comment: Читайте сообщение об ошибке. Там в тексте сообщения написано, что именно у вас не так. И изучайте синтаксис, тогда таких ошибок появляться не будет. А если уж никак не можете понять причину, приведите по крайней мере текст сообщения и укажите, на какое место кода он ругается. А такие вопросы здесь не приветствуются, и этот, скорее всего, будет удалён.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
parisTour.ayazhanRoute();
```

Вызывается вне метода

Comment: Пробовал, так же выдает ошибку

Comment: Извините, все сработало. Спасибо за ответь